# Android LisPopUpWindow Stays On Right Side of view without Margin

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I am trying to implement a `ListPopUpWindow` something like the `twitter` like Menu `Popup`. But then it's stuck to the right side of the screen. Any help would be appreciated thanks. My code's below

**PopUpWindow Method**

```
 private void onListPopUp(View anchor) {

    ArrayList<Person> persoonItem = new ArrayList<>();
    persoonItem.add(new Person(R.drawable.ic_profile_logo, "Oladeji Abubakar", "abubakar.oladeji@deliveryscience.co", ""));
    persoonItem.add(new Person(0, "", "", "Update Phone"));
    persoonItem.add(new Person(0, "", "", "Your Cards"));
    persoonItem.add(new Person(0, "", "", "Invite Friends"));
    persoonItem.add(new Person(0, "", "", "Logout"));

    ListPopupWindowAdapter mListPopUpWindowAdapter = new ListPopupWindowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), persoonItem);

    final ListPopupWindow pop = new ListPopupWindow(this);
    pop.setAdapter(mListPopUpWindowAdapter);
    pop.setAnchorView(anchor);
    pop.setModal(true);
    pop.setContentWidth(toolbar.getWidth() / 2);
    pop.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    pop.setVerticalOffset(-105);
    //pop.setHorizontalOffset(100);
    //pop.setPromptPosition(20);
    //pop.setHorizontalOffset();
    pop.setPromptPosition(0);
    pop.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            pop.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Clicked" + ((Person) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getOthers(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    pop.show();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(toolbar.getWidth()/2, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    wlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.END;
    wlp.horizontalMargin = -20;
    wlp.x = -20;
    View parentView = (View) pop.getListView().getParent();
    parentView.setLayoutParams(wlp);
}
```

And the image

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Comment: does this popup has an xml file ??
please show your layout also

Comment: Nope. Just the ListItems has have two XML. One for the first row and the second for the remaining of the rows

Comment: ok, you want from your popup to be shown in the middle ??

Comment: Nope. Just let's say 10-20 margin before the right. I've edited my question

Comment: i think that the best solution is to make your own popup, so you can manage it as you can. You can find a lot of tutorial about that ;)

Comment: Well, I am making mine using a ListPopWindow. It's not the normal Menu Item

Comment: you make it without xml file ?? ok if it's only java code than you must change some attributes to be placed in the choosen area ;)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I am trying to write a custom dropdown list for a toolbar however I can't seem to shift the dropdown layout from the right-hand edge of the screen. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can offset the ListPopupWindow by using [ListPopupWindow#setHorizontalOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#setHorizontalOffset(int)) and [ListPopupWindow#setVerticalOffset](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#setVerticalOffset(int)).

What is confusing is that if your anchor is positioned on the right of the screen you need to add the width value of your ListPopupWindow to the horizontal offset while the vertical offset is always 0 based. Using values below the width for the horizontal offset when the ListPopupWindow is anchored to the right seems to not have any effect. Also positive in the horizontal axis is pointing to the right so we invert the horizontal value.

The following Code positions the ListPopupWindow 5dp down and 5dp to the left from an anchor positioned on the top right:

```
  final ListPopupWindow popupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(context);

  int widthPixels = convertDpToPixels(200, context);
  int horizontalOffset = -(widthPixels + convertDpToPixels(5, context));
  int verticaloffset = convertDpToPixels(5, context);

  popupWindow.setAnchorView(anchor);
  popupWindow.setWidth(widthPixels);
  popupWindow.setHorizontalOffset(horizontalOffset);
  popupWindow.setVerticalOffset(verticaloffset);
```